# What does "awaiting reviewer selection" really mean under the "minor revision" scenario?

Tags: publications, peer-review

I just submitted a revised paper to ScholarOne (minor revision). I suppose that in most cases (of minor revision), the revised manuscript will only be reviewed by the ADM or associate editor. However, I just noticed that the status of my revised manuscript is now "awaiting reviewer selection". Does this entail that the revised manuscript has to go back to the original reviewer for (final) re-review? Or, could it be that it is an automatic status message showing that the editor is now reading/evaluating my revised manuscript and that this does not necessary mean that the revised paper has to go back to the original reviewer? Thanks for your insight in advance.

Comment: A plausible guess is that the editorial software uses "awaiting reviewer selection" to mean that the manuscript has been received but has not been sent to a reviewer. If the manuscript is only going to be checked by an editor and not by an external reviewer, then, of course, it's in the situation I described --- received and not sent to a reviewer --- but the software's code for this situation --- awaiting reviewer selection --- is completely misleading.

Comment: They may genuinely have to select new reviewers, if they want to send the revision out for review. There are several journals I review for where you can opt-out of re-reviewing a revision.

Comment: @AndreasBlass "If the manuscript is only going to be checked by an editor and not by an external reviewer..." is an unknown. I've had minor revisions sent out for review, both as an author and reviewer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to recollect how the statuses changed when you submitted the paper the first time.

Scenario 1: with editor/under editor evaluation >> awaiting reviewer selection >> under review 
If this is how the status had changed the first time you submitted the paper, then chances are that your paper is actually being sent for a re-review.

Scenario 2: awaiting reviewer selection>> under review
If this was the way the status had changed, then it is possible that the online status tracking software uses the status "awaiting reviewer selection" to indicate that the paper is with the editor.

Comment: Thank you very much for your insight. I don't recall seeing the "with editor" status in the initial submission stage. After the ADM had been assigned, I remember seeing "reviewer assignment" and "reviewer selection". And then the status automatically changed to "under review". I assume that it is more similar to the second scenario that you noted.

Comment: After having a second thought, I am still a bit confused. If this is the 2nd scenario noted above--that ScholarOne uses the status "awaiting reviewer selection" to indicate that the paper is with the editor and will only be reviewed by the editor (after the submission of a revised manuscript)--why it does not directly indicate the status "awaiting final (EIC) decision"?

Comment: Possibly, the default status does not directly show "awaiting final decision" to give the editor the freedom to send the manuscript for a re-review if the editor feels it is required. Additionally, it might be difficult to have different settings on the tracking system for revised submissions, but I agree that the status "awaiting reviewer selection" can be misleading and there should be another status such as "with editor" to clarify this.